# `mvn -Drevision=some-revision generate-sources` could not resolve dependencies for multi module project

Tags: java, maven

When I run `mvn -Drevision=some-reversion generate-sources`

I'm getting the following error:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project my-project2: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.mine:my-project2:jar:some-reversion: com.mine:my-project1:jar:some-reversion was not found in https://.../repository/maven-public/ during a previous attempt. This failure was cached in the local repository and resolution is not reattempted until the update interval of ... has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]

Snippet of my-project1.pom

```xml
<project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>my-project1</artifactId>
    <name>my-project1</name>
    <version>${revision}</version>
    ....
```

Snippet of my-project2.pom

```xml
<project>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mine</groupId>
            <artifactId>my-project1</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Is there a way to some how exclude this submodule dependency when running `generate-source`, as it won't exists locally until the module has been packaged? My main goal is to just download all the remote dependencies.